# How to create(or switch) xa-data-source using CLI in Wildfly?

Tags: datasource, command-line-interface, wildfly

Hi I need to dynamicaly switch datasource using CLI.
How can I do this ?
This manual has some examples:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes

I want to delete old xa-data-source and create new.
But it does not works.
This command:

```
xa-data-source add \
    --name=TestXADS \
    --driver-name=postgresql \
    --jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/TestXADS \
    --user-name=demouser \
    --password=password \
    --recovery-username= demouser \
    --recovery-password = password \
    --use-ccm=false \
    --max-pool-size=25 \
    --blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000 \
    --new-connection-sql="set datestyle = ISO, European;"
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-datasource-properties=ServerName:add(value=localhost)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-datasource-properties=PortNumber:add(value=5432)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-datasource-properties=DatabaseName:add(value=arctic_naryan)
xa-data-source enable --name = TestXADS
```

gives this result:

```
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] xa-data-source add \
>     --name=TestXADS \
>     --driver-name=postgresql \
>     --jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/TestXADS \
>     --user-name=demouser \
>     --password=password \
>     --recovery-username= demouser \
>     --recovery-password = password \
>     --use-ccm=false \
>     --max-pool-size=25 \
>     --blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000 \
>     --new-connection-sql="set datestyle = ISO, European;"
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:
" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS010469: At least one xa-datasource-property is
required for an xa-datasource"}}

[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-
datasource-properties=ServerName:add(value=localhost)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014766: Resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\"),
    (\"xa-datasource-properties\" => \"ServerName\")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-
datasource-properties=PortNumber:add(value=5432)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014766: Resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\"),
    (\"xa-datasource-properties\" => \"PortNumber\")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestXADS/xa-
datasource-properties=DatabaseName:add(value=arctic_naryan)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014766: Resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"xa-data-source\" => \"TestXADS\"),
    (\"xa-datasource-properties\" => \"DatabaseName\")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] xa-data-source enable --name = TestXADS
```

It is example from manual. Why it doesnt works?

upd.
Tried to exec this command(according Wildfly manual)

```
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source add --name=TestXADS  --driver-name=postgresql --jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/TestXADS
```

but it doesnt help

```
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source add --name=T
estXADS  --driver-name=postgresql --jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/TestXADS
Can't proceed with node type 'TestXADS--driver-name' until the node name for the
 previous node type has been specified.
[standalone@127.0.0.1:9990 /]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're referencing is not for WildFly, but for JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. Most operations work the same, but some have changed. See the new [CLI recipes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes) for further information.

If you're attempting to conditionally add or remove a data source also have a look at the [if-else control flow](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/If-elseControlFlow).